# Microsoft Teams - downloading a file from within a tab

Tags: file, download, microsoft-teams, spfx

I've created a configurable tab app and have side-loaded it into Teams. On the content page, I want to allow the user to download a file. Simply linking to the file doesn't work. When the user clicks the link, the content iframe redirects and goes blank. I've tested this in the web app version of Teams at teams.microsoft.com and it works fine. The file gets downloaded as you would expect.

If it makes any difference, the content page is hosted in SharePoint on a modern page using SPFx.

Comment: We're looking into it. Thanks for reporting the problem.

Comment: Derek - can you post the HTML that's invoking the download? In particular we're wondering whether it has a "target=" attribute.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Thanks for looking into this. `target` attribute is not being used. I'm using the React version of SPFx and so using the Link component with the href attribute like this: `<Link href={item.serverRelativeUrl}>{item.name}</Link>` which resolves to `<a href="/sites/MyDevSite/Shared Documents/Test Document 1.docx" class="ms-Link root_63fb318e isEnabled_63fb318e" tabindex="-1">Test Document 1.docx</a>`

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT any update or ETA for a fix on this? Thanks

Comment: We're still investigating it (your HTML is helpful). In your case there are two problems: one, that your tab navigates to a blank page, and two, that the download doesn't occur. Can you check your "downloads" directory and see if the download indeed happened? There's a UI problem that nothing shows the download is occurring, but in our testing it actually does. We haven't seen the blank page problem.

Comment: Hi, I was experiencing something similar linking sts files & handling custom protocols. I believe it has something to do with electron & how the teams app was created - Same thing using it on chrome.  https://jaxenter.com/critical-electron-vulnerability-windows-apps-140870.html

Comment: This is still not fixed.

Comment: Apparently not fixed yet. Pressing the link and page iframe goes blank in web version (in Edge) or ignored in Windows client and web client under Firefox. 
@BillBliss-MSFT do you have any news regarding the issue?

Comment: It turned out to be CSP problem. Tab page has to return proper headers if I understood correctly.